# The matlab genetic algorithm returns higher fitness value than when starts (with linear constraint)?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, genetic-algorithm

The genetic algorithm is returning a value with higher fitness value than when it started.

Is this coming from my options?

The problem seems to be the linear constraint sum of three variables to equal 1. But how can I impose it and still have the ga working ? Without constraint is finding minimum.

```
ConstraintFunction = @simple_constraint;

options = gaoptimset('MutationFcn',@mutationadaptfeasible);

options = gaoptimset(...
'PopulationSize', 150);
options = gaoptimset(options,'Generations',150,'StallGenLimit', 140);
X0 = [0.35 0.22 0.12 0 0.4 0.6]; % Start point (row vector)
options = gaoptimset(options,'InitialPopulation',X0);
options = gaoptimset(options,'PlotFcns',{@gaplotbestf, @gaplotstopping});

% rng(0, 'twister');
rng(1,'twister') % for reproducibility

[x,fval] = ga(ObjectiveFunction,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,ConstraintFunction,options)

function [c, ceq] = simple_constraint(x)
c = [];
ceq = [(x(4) + x(5) + x(6) -1)];
```

Optimization terminated: average change in the fitness value less than options.TolFun
 and constraint violation is less than options.TolCon.

[image: results]

Comment: Of course, genetic algorithms maximize fitness function.

Comment: Good point. But matlab genetic algorithm works as minimization I believe. http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/setting-the-maximum-number-of-generations.html